# How to connect from ASP.NET Core web application to SQL Server using Negotiate authentication method?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, kerberos

I have the following application structure:

```
[Windows with Chrome browser] -> [ASP.NET Core app on Windows or Linux] -> [SQL Server on Windows]
```

All three machines are included into a domain and the idea is to connect from ASP.NET app to SQL Server with Trusted Connection parameter enabled. The connection to SQL Server should be established using the credentials of the user with Chrome browser who is logged in to the domain.

How do I implement this? My idea is to use ASP.NET Core's Negotiate authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();
```

And then use RunImpersonated method to establish the connection:

```
var callerIdentity = User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(callerIdentity.AccessToken, () =>
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection("...;Trusted Connection=True;...");
    conn.Connect();
});
```

Is this a valid thing to do? And are there better options for using user's credentials for connecting to SQL Server?

Comment: Did you view this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ntlm-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Yes, but that is tutorial for JDBC.